# Troubleshooting Silverlight databindings

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding

This post intends to give all the possible solutions to a very common and time consuming issue in Silverlight where bindings don't work.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TextValue}"/>

public class ViewModel
{
    // ...
    public string TextValue { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Suppose either the property or the TextBox won't refresh properly.

Comment: Not actually an answer, but a hint. When troubleshooting binding issues, associating a mock converter might help to identify the problem. Setting a breakpoint in the Convert and ConvertBack methods, will let us see if the target property was called successfully. If the breakpoints are not hit, it means that there is a problem with the target property or the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The binding has a different datacontext.**

This example won't work since the item template has a different datacontext:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding TextValue}"/>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The target class doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged.**

The class containing the bound property needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise PropertyChanged when the value of the bound property changes.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //...
    private string textValue;
    public string TextValue
    {
        get { return textValue; }
        set
        {
            textValue = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TextValue"));
            }
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The datacontext is null.**

The example above will never work if the datacontext is not associated:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The binding mode is not well specified.**

The example above needs to be in TwoWay mode if we want the TextValue property to be updated:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TextValue, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

By default, the mode is OneWay, which means that the control content will be updated when the property changes.

Answer (score 0):

**The converter is not well associated.**

The most common way to associate the converter is through a static resource. Make sure the key name is well written.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <converters:AValueConverter x:Key="AValueConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

<TextBox Text="{Binding TextValue, Converter={StaticResource AValueConverter}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The target property is not well written or doesn't exist.**

In this case, the converter won't be called.

Answer (score 0):

**Some property on the path to the target property or the containing class is null or not visible.**

The containing page or user control should have access to the target property. Also if some of the properties on the path are null, it will fail silently.

If the target property is null, [TargetNullValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx) might be helpful.